# How to order by multiple fields using standard query_posts?

Tags: loop, query-posts

In our `archive.php` we show all the items which match our selected category. This works absolutely fine.

Then we improved it by adding (just before the loop) a sort and upping the posts per page from the default 10, like so:

```
$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=99');
```

This works even better.

Now, however we want to sort by more than one field, say `menu_order` then `title`. I don't see a way to do this using this query_posts / querystring syntax we have in place. Code samples all involve firing up a new WP_Query, losing track of the query_string. What's the solution?

Comment: Never use `query_posts`. See [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/176708/4771) and [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/169999/4771) for some hints on using `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: @Milo i'm looking at those links now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're altering the main query, always use `pre_get_posts` to alter query parameters *before* the query is run and before the template is loaded. This will be the most efficient and will not break pagination. As of v4, `orderby` accepts an array of arguments, which gives you the ability to have different `order` for each if necessary:

```
function my_get_posts( $query ){
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 ); // show all posts
        $query->set( 'orderby', array('menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is ability to sort by more than one column. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 99,
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order title',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
// do your stuff here...

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Check out [standard loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop) and why you should use `wp_reset_postdata`.

Comment: yeah but what about query_posts? your fresh WP_Query will ignore that

Comment: Same thing, only `query_posts` is slower, check here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts. Quote "This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes.". Anyway, did you try `$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=menu_order title&order=asc&posts_per_page=99');`?